# Best way to know if my environment has workload repository license

Tags: oracle, tuning, awr

Usually, when I need to use something that use some resource from awr, I look for `LAST_USAGE_DATE` at `dba_feature_usage_statistics` with feature name `Automatic Workload Repository`, but I'm almost sure this is not a good way.

How I know if my environment has workload repository license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the contract.

Oracle does not technically limit installing and using features, anything can be installed, whatever you have in the database may not reflect what you are allowed to use. It is the responsibility of the DBA to not install or disable unlicensed features wherever it is possible.

Starting with 11g, there is a parameter called [CONTROL_MANAGEMENT_PACK_ACCESS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/CONTROL_MANAGEMENT_PACK_ACCESS.html#GUID-A5CA11BA-AE1F-4A2E-9C59-A98BA1F4E5C2). Its default value enables both Diagnostic and Tuning Packs, but in a properly managed environment it should be set according to the license. When the value of the parameter includes `DIAGNOSTIC`, then Diagnostic Pack (which includes AWR) is enabled, otherwise it is disabled.

Comment: Yes, the problem is sometimes it's hard to have this information from the customer, mainly when you need to resolve some problem faster as possible with some resource from awr that can help me